# Mysql trigger to insert a new row into another table after an update

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a trigger that will warn us when a job is completed in an unusually quick way (less than 70% estimated time) so that somebody can go check if there has been an error.

There's a job table that looks like this:

```
id
machine_id
estimated_time
hour_of_completion
state (this is 0 for unfinished jobs and 1 for finished ones)
```

A job has many subjobs so there's also a subjob table that looks like this:

```
id
job_id (references job.job_id)
subjob_time (this is in seconds)
```

And the warning table where we want to log the warnings:

```
id (auto_increment)
machine_id
hour_of_completion (this is the time of the day when the job finished)
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `job_too_quick` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `job_too_quick` $$
AFTER UPDATE ON `job`
BEGIN
  IF OLD.state <> NEW.state AND NEW.state = 1 THEN
    IF (SELECT sum(subjob_time)
        FROM subjob
        WHERE job_id = OLD.id)
        <
        (TIME_TO_SEC(NEW.estimated_time) * 0.7) THEN
          INSERT INTO warnings (machine_id, hour_of_completion)
          VALUES (OLD.machine_id, OLD.hour_of_completion);
        END;
     END IF;
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But when I try to run it I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AFTER UPDATE ON `jobs`
BEGIN
  IF OLD.state <> NEW.state AND NEW.s' at line 1
```

I feel like I must be making some silly syntax mistake but I'm going crazy trying to find out what it is. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe you are missing the syntax `FOR EACH ROW` right after `BEGIN`?

Comment: You can change the line as `AFTER UPDATE ON 'job' FOR EACH ROW `

Comment: Yes thank you!! I was indeed missing that. That's two hours down the drain and now I feel embarrassed to boot :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody has a similar problem, the mistake was indeed quite embarrassingly silly, I was missing FOR EACH ROW as the people on the comments so helpfully pointed out.